# convert split strings in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have three text fields in my cricket score board application.

If I click on every action button, I would like to count every each overs by 0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5

It should be 1.0 after 0.5 and then it should continue as 1.1,1.2.......1.5,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,3.1...

For each and every action button please help me for this

```
IBOutlet UITextField *score;
IBOutlet UITextField *wickets;
IBOutlet UITextField *overs;

-(IBAction)dot:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)extras:(id)sender;
```

This is I have tried:

```
-(IBAction)dot:(id)sender
{
  if( txtOvers.Text.split(“.”)[1]! = 5 )
    txtOver.text = txtOver.Text + .1; 
  else 
    txtOver.text = 0.5;
}
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: -(IBAction)dot:(id)sender{
    if(txtOvers.Text.split(“.”)[1]!=5
       txtOver.text=txtOver.Text+.1;
      else
       txtOver.text=o.5;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *txtOver;\

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.txtOver.text = @"0.1";
}

-(IBAction)dot:(id)sender
{ 
  NSArray *textSplitCollection = [self.txtOver.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

  int lastPrecisionValue = ([textSplitCollection count] > 1)?[[textSplitCollection objectAtIndex:1] intValue]:0;

   if (5 == lastPrecisionValue)
   {
      self.txtOver.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.01f", [self.txtOver.text floatValue] +  0.5];
   }
   else
   {
      self.txtOver.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.01f", [self.txtOver.text floatValue] +  0.1];
   }
}
```